# How to setTimeout to provide over_query_limit

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have been "struggling" for days with a code snippet that is supposed to output a google map ( v3 with API key ) with multiple addresses.

Up to the point where I had not exceeded a number of "12", this was all nice. Now I have 12 addresses I get an "over_query_limit" error with the 12th address.

Before this post is immediately blocked or deleted, I have read all of the existing threads and none of the answers fits my problem.

Since I am not really "fit" in JS, it would be great if one of you could help me.

In my map.js am iterating over an array that looks like this

```
      $addresses[] = [$item->userCompany, 
                    $item->userStrasse.", ".
                    $item->userPlz." ".$item->userOrt, 
                    "eintrag/".$item->userEntryUrl,
                    $iconMarker
                    ];  
   <script>  
        var locations = <?php echo json_encode($addresses, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
    </script>
```

that's what I do with this code:

```
    function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.9027636, 49.8988135),
        maxZoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            geocodeAddress(locations, i);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeAddress(locations, i) {
    var title = locations[i][0];
    var address = locations[i][1];
    var url = locations[i][2];
    var markerImage = locations[i][3];
    **geocoder.geocode({
        'address': locations[i][1]
    },**

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                //icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
                icon: markerImage,
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                address: address,
                url: url
            })
            infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        } else {
            //alert("geocode of " + address + " failed:" + status);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I add a "setTimeout" here, so that this "over_query_limit" error can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with the timeout is that it delays each loop, but asynchronously.  So they all end up stacked together anyway at the end of the delays.

However, if we increase our `setTimeout()` length each time by multiplying by `i`, it may work.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(geocodeAddress(locations, i), 1000 * i);            
}
```

Now if that doesn't work, try this custom sleep function, it might work also.

```
function sleep(milliSeconds) {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
}
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        geocodeAddress(locations, i);
        sleep(2200);
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks,
i already tried this without any effect. nevertheless the error appears.
Any other ideas?

Comment: many thanks for your support.
the first one has also no effect, even when i increase the timeout to 4500, the maps comes up immediately, but also stops after the 11thd entry. that means, the 12thd entra is not shown.
The second one already shows an error on the editor. couldn´t try this one. maybe some "komma" is missing oir someting.

Comment: @itsberni can you try now?

Comment: sorry - no. is this the right place to implement this timeout?